# vscode suppress pydev error highlighting while typing

Tags: visual-studio-code, pydev

does anybody has a nice trick to solve the issue of this annoying error highlighting while I am typing code in the editor. I use pydev because of the good import functionality. Unfortunately the config-possibilities of pydev are not that extensive as they were in good old eclipse-times :(
Another hack by suppressing outputs of specific extensions is also imaginable, but couldn't find anything.
Thx in advance and greetz

I also tried to explore the extension-files in ~/.vscode-oss/extensions/fabioz.vscode-pydev-0.4.0/server/config_linux --- but all those references... :|